# How to print x as 0x where x is an integer C++

Tags: c++, cout

I want to print out  a time like minutes:second.miliseconds . 
Think about that time is 4 minutes 2 seconds 65 miliseconds
instead of writing it like 4:2.65 I want to write it like 4:02.065 
how can I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use iostream or stringstream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
[...]
int val = 1;
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << val << std::endl;
[...]
```

std::setw sets the width of the following element.

std::setfill sets the character which fills the empty space.

Answer (score 5):

You'd use `iomanip` for that

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
//intermediate code goes here
std::cout << minutes << ":" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << seconds << "." << std::setw(3) << milliseconds << std::endl;
```

Comment: Worth noting that some I/O manipulators are "just for the next output", and others are "sticky" until changed.  Some people instead do the formatting to a stringstream and then output the results in the desired stream; others save/restore the state of the stream (Boost has a nice helper utility to do that).